# Django how to migrate new models with existing model

Tags: django

IS there is any option to update new field with existing model in django 1.4.I have class name personaldetails having fields "name", "dob", "age" in models.py. Now i want to add new field "location" in the class.how to sync this new field in existing table.

Comment: did you got a solution for your problem?

Comment: @abda2005 No, you suggest dbshell that's manual process. Every time i want to alter the table if I do any changes in model. you have any other idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a plugin like [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) to achieve this

Comment: yes it works with Django 1.4 check this [link](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/0.7.4.html) for reference

Answer (score 1):

a very simple way to do it without south migration.

```
first add the field name in your model and get under the shell type

$ python manage.py dbshell 

you will get directly within your database shell (mysql or psql) it up to what database
you are using.

mysql> | psql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD column varchar(100);

and it will add the new column to your table, doesn't matter if the table it already
  populated or not.

$ python manage.py syncdb
```

and that's it and you good